# A problem involving the null space and possibly the Schur complement

Tags: matrices

Consider a matrix $A = V V^T$, where $V$ is an $n \times m (m < n)$ matrix such that $V^T V = I$ (an identity matrix). Obviously $A$ is a projector so $B = I - A = W W^T$, where $W$ is an $n \times (m-n)$ matrix such that $W^T W = I$.

Consider the expression $W (W^T Q W)^{-1} W^T$, where $Q$ is diagonal.  My question is: is there a closed-form of this expression that depends only on $Q$ and $V$?

I was able to reduce many similar expressions using the Schur complement but this one I am unable to tackle.